# Como Hago para retroceder a una version antigua de IDE Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo de Desarrollador de Android y quiero saber como cambiar a una version antigua.

Answer (score 3):

Podés enconrtrar las versiones anteriores [acá](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?hl=es-419)
Pero pensalo dos veces porque para desarrollar apps para andriod tendrias que usar siempre la versión mas actual del producto.